# Convert Array of Object to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I have an array who look like this:

```
tab [
    0: {
        firstName: John,
        lastName: Doe,            
        situation: married,
        familyMembers: 5,
    }
    1: {
        firstName: Jack,
        lastName: Daniel,
        situation: single,
        familyMembers: 6,
    }
]
```

I need something like this:

```
{
    [John]: {[Doe]: 5,
    [Jack]: {[Daniel]: 6,
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
tab.map((item) => {
    return (
        {[item.firstName]: {[item.lastName]: item.familyMembers}}
    )
})
```

But even without considering that I have an array instead of an object the result look like this:

```
[
    0: {
        [John]: {[Doe]: 5,
    }
    1: {
        [Jack]: {[Daniel]: 6,
    }
]
```

Any suggestion here will be appreciate I tried using reduce but as I probably don't use it well it make really bad result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you wnat the names as keys, yxou could build the entries and from it the object.

```js
var tab = [{ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', situation: 'maried', familyMembers: 5 }, { firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Daniel', situation: 'single', familyMembers: 6 }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(tab.map(({ firstName, lastName, familyMembers }) =>
        [firstName, { [lastName]: familyMembers }]
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`map()` always returns an array of the results of the function.

You can use `reduce()` instead

```js
var tab = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    situation: 'maried',
    familyMembers: 5,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jack',
    lastName: 'Daniel',
    situation: 'single',
    familyMembers: 6,
  }
];
var result = tab.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.firstName] = {
    [item.lastName]: item.familyMembers
  };
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```